# Scrolling to view textbox in UITableView footer

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, footer

I have a textbox to enter a code in UITableView footer.

When I click the text box I get the keyboard appearing but I am not sure how I could get the UITableView to scroll so that the text box is visible

Any code sample for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this code from a previous SO question.

```
 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        if(textField == birthdayTextField)
            [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
    }


    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        if(textField == birthdayTextField)
            [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
    }

    - (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
    {
        const int movementDistance = 80;  //change this around
        const float movementDuration = 0.3f; //change this around

        int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

        [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

since the footer cant scroll any higher the the lowest point of the tableview, you will need to move the tableview up to to show the textbox.

There is a nice blogpost here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html